# Binomial theorem in a field of cardinality q=p^r

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field, binomial-theorem

If $a$ and $b$ are roots of the polynom $X^q -  X$, how do you show that $$(a+b)^q = a^q + b^q$$

Thanks!

Comment: The title contains crucial information that is absent in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In any field of characteristic $p$, $(a+b)^q=a^q+b^q$
for any $a$ and $b$ and any $q$ which is a power of $p$. This follows
by induction from $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ (which follows from the binomial theorem).